MAUI - Binding to nested properties in Collection. OnPropertyChanged relay in Markdown
I have quite complicated setup and i am missing something. The bindings are working, but OnPropertyChanged does not refresh the view when i call the UpdateValue method.
When i get a message with new data i update the values in SinglePropertyConfigs using the UpdateValue method.
Minimal size models
public partial class SingleAxisConfig() : ObservableObject
{    
    public ObservableCollection<AxisDisplay> Displays;
}

public partial class AxisDisplay : ObservableObject
{   
    [ObservableProperty]
    private UnitEnum unit;
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Value))]
    private Quantity? quantity = null;
    public string Value =>  (Quantity is null || 
double.IsNaN(Quantity.Value)) ? DefValue: 
Quantity.Value.ToString(ValueFormat);
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Value))]
    private string defValue = "---";
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Value))]
    private string valueFormat  = "#0.000";  
}

ViewModel
public partial class AxisViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<SingleAxisConfig> AxisConfigsInOrder
...
}

View
public AxisView(AxisViewModel vm) : base(vm)
{
    var axisConfigTemplate = new AxisConfigTemplate();
    Content = new CollectionView
    {
        ItemTemplate = axisConfigTemplate
    }.Bind(CollectionView.ItemsSourceProperty, nameof(vm.AxisConfigsInOrder));
}

Inside The template i bind like this
new Label()   
.Bind(Label.TextProperty, 
static (SingleAxisConfig model) => model.Displays[2].Value, 
mode: BindingMode.OneWay),

I do call the update method based on messages.
private void OnListAxisRecieved(Dictionary<string, AxisModel> axisDict)
{
    foreach (var (key, value) in axisDict)
    {
        var axis = Axis.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Identity == key);
        if (axis == null)
        {
            Axis.Add(value);
        }
        else
        {
            axis.CopyAllInternalProperties(value);
        }
        foreach (var axisDisp in AxisConfigsInOrder)
        {
            if (axisDict.TryGetValue(axisDisp.AxisIdentity, out axis))
            {
                axisDisp.Display.Quantity = 
    axis.GetQuantity(axisDisp.Display.Label);
            }
        }
    }
}

I do think that the problem is the dot call in the binding but i just cant figure how to do it.
I have found this https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui.Markup/discussions/203, but cant implement it sucesfully.
I did further testing, when i load my configuration i add method for OnPropertyChanged.
foreach (var item in AxisConfigsInOrder)
{
    item.PropertyChanged += MonitoredItem_PropertyChanged;
    item.Display.PropertyChanged += MonitoredItem_PropertyChanged;
} 
private void MonitoredItem_PropertyChanged(object? sender, 
PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
Trace.WriteLine($"The {nameof(sender)} object with Name {sender} 
has a change in its property {e.PropertyName} ");
}

in the trace i do see
The sender object with Name Aicra.Axis.Standard.Model.AxisDisplay has a change in its property Value
The sender object with Name Aicra.Axis.Standard.Model.AxisDisplay has a change in its property Quantity
The sender object with Name Aicra.Axis.Standard.Model.SingleAxisConfig has a change in its property Display
But the UI is not redrawing.

I cannot see how UpdateValue is being called. I cannot see anything wrong with the implementation.
However Value appears to be a derivative of Quantity and ValueFormat, I would rewrite AxisDisplay as:
public partial class AxisDisplay : ObservableObject
{   
    [ObservableProperty]
    private UnitEnum unit;
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Value))]
    private Quantity? quantity = null;
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Value))]
    private string valueFormat  = "#0.000";
    public string Value
        => (Quantity is null || double.IsNaN(Quantity.Value))
         ? "---"
         : Quantity.Value.ToString(ValueFormat);
}


I edited my answer to provide aditional info +rewrote the AxisDisplay based on your comment
